# Do sensors show values using amps?

Tags: sensor

Take a generic sensor, let's say for water level. Do they generally work like this: 20 mA = 100% full, 15 mA = 50%, 10 mA = 0% water and 0 mA = fault, no sensor detected?

Do you guys have multimeters that can measure such small currents, to see if your sensor is working correctly?

[image]

Comment: @llVIU, Have you got a multimeter? What is it's lowest DC amps sensitivity?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `Do you guys have multimeters ...?` is a poll question ... that type of a question is not allowed here  because all answers are correct

Comment: There are meters designed especially for 4-20mA current loop sensors. The average digital multimeter should have a suitable low current range or failing that, use a  100 Ohm resistor and measure the voltage across it. 2V = 20mA

Answer (score 3):

> Take a generic sensor,

There is no *general* "sensor" interface, although there are some that are more popular than others.

> let's say for the water level, do they generally work that... 20mA=100%,...10mA=0%,... and 0mA=fault..?

One of the most popular analog interfaces in industrial settings is a [*4-20mA current loop*](https://www.prelectronics.com/the-fundamentals-of-4-20-ma-current-loops/). But, the bottom of the scale is 4mA, not 10mA. 4mA at 12 or 24V provides enough power for those sensors that need to be powered all the time, and the difference between 4mA and 0mA is big enough for reliable detection of a broken loop.

Answer (score 0):

Generally 20mA is the full scale reading of the sensor or signal conditioner, and 4mA is the low end. Similarly with other process control standards such as 0-10V or 1-5V or 1-5mA, or even 3-15 PSI.

What that 0% 'zero' and 100% full scale reading actually represents in 'engineering units' of gallons, centimetres or cow-acres is dependent on the sensor as well as the application of the sensor.

For example for a comfort heating application I might choose to have fairly narrow signal conditioner range of (say) 5~45°C even though the sensor itself is an RTD capable of reading from -200 to 600°C. Or your tank level might indicate from 80% full to 110% for 4-20mA since I might mostly be interested in when to turn on and off a pump around 100% full.

Reading currents in the 0-20mA range is well within the capability of many (even inexpensive) multimeters. Accuracy will vary with the instrument, of course. Since it is the current that needs to be measured, the circuit must be interrupted and then re-established through the meter in order to read the current with a multimeter which may not always be convenient. And if the technician forgets to return the multimeter to voltage mode before attempting to measure (say) loop supply voltage then a ready source of replacement fuses might be necessary.

Of course there are indicators that will map the 4-20mA or 0-100% into engineering units for you. Linearly (perhaps with an offset zero) and  there are ones that can do it nonlinearly, or you can do it in software.